# If statement for when a date is within a date range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I am creating a flag that generates 1 when condition is satisfied, else 0

I am trying to get to this state

[image]

I want to create a code that if `df['Won'] = 1` **or** `'2018-10-31' < df['Created Date'] < '2018-12-01'` then it will return 1, else 0

Currently my code is:

```
df['Deal'] = pd.np.where((df['Won'] == 1) | (df['Created Date']>'2018-10-31'), 1, 0)
```

I am not sure how to fix my code

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include your dataframe as text, not as an image. But also, if it will return 1 if `df['Won']` is `1`, then they *should* all be 1s, because even the third row has `Won==1`

Comment: Hi Sacul, Yes I typed it wrong, there should be a 0 for row three in the "Won" column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Deal'] = (df['Won'] == 1) | ( (df['Created Date']>'2018-10-31') & (df['Created Date']<'2018-12-01') )
```

This will return a bool, which you can convert to an int if you'd like, with an astype(int) command. Also, I'd recommend converting those date strings to actual datetime objects with something like

```
df['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created Date'])
```

then your df['Deal'] query would have something more like

```
df['Created Date'] > dt.datetime(2018,10,31).
```

Comment: `pandas` is actually very good at handling date comparisons. With `datetime64` columns you can directly compare to strings. `df['Created Date'].between('2018-10-31', '2018-12-01', inclusive=False)` (and using `.between` to add some nice syntax)

Comment: Thank you n3utrino and ALollz! I actually used ALollz's solution and put that right into my original formula